# What is the name of a flattened form of set representation consisting only of unions of subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, set-theory

I would like to give a name to the form (say XYZ form) where a set is only represented as union of its subsets and the subsets are mutually disjoint and themselves only represented either as explicit enumeration of elements or in X form themselves. The question is, if there is already a well-known name for this form?

Essentially, if $U$ is a universal set. A set representation of a set $R$ of a set $X \subset U$ is said to be in XYZ form if

1. $R$ has the form  $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$. (The elements are all listed explicitly)
2. $X = Y \cup Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are in XYZ form.

Examples:

1. $A =  \{a\}$ is in XYZ form.
2. $B = \{b,c\}$ is in XYZ form
3. $A \cup B$ is in $XYZ$ form
4. XYZ form of $A \times B$ would be $\{(a,b),(a,c)\}$ or it could be $\{(a,b) \} \cup \{(a,c)\}$
5. Let the universal set $U$ be $\{a,b,c\}$, and $A=\{a\}$, and $B=\{b\}$ then the XYZ form of $(A \cup B)^c $ would be $\{c\}$.
6. $A \cap B$ is not in XYZ form. The XYZ form of $A \cap B$ is $\{\}$ (the empty set)

Comment: Apologies for incorrect notation. Used ordered pairs to fix it now.

Comment: Isn't this just the usual set literal notation but allowing "$\}\cup\{$" in place of ","?

Comment: I think they're referred to as a union of (mutually) disjoint sets; or even as a disjoint union of sets.